# RewiteRule not working in .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm making a website in PHP and I've got to the part where I need to make a news page.
I have already written the `news.php` file and it uses `GET` to read the particular title of the article to display. That means I end up with an URL like

`/community/news.php?title=post-title`

And I much rather like it to be like

`/community/news/post-title`

So I looked it up and saw I could do it with the .htaccess file.

Now, my actual .htaccess file looks exactly like this

```
ErrorDocument 404 /notfound.php

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

# /community/news/post-title -> /community/news.php?title=post-title
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^community/news/([^/]*)$ /community/news.php?title=$1 [L]

</IfModule>
```

And the result of going to `/community/news/post-title` it's a 404 Error

Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks a lot for your help.

Turns out it was an issue with relative paths. 
It worked with:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

# /community/news/post-title -> /community/news.php?title=post-title
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^/community/news/([^/]*)$ community/news.php?title=$1 [L]

</IfModule>
```

(the difference is in the '/'s of the last line)

Answer (score 0):

If you work in local environment and your url is like http://localhost/website/community/news/post-title the you should have "website" in "RewriteBase /"

```
RewriteBase /website
```

Answer (score 0):

So, assuming your url is example.com - (the QSA flag appends the query string string to the url)

```
RewriteEngine On

ErrorDocument 404 example.com/notfound.php

# /community/news/post-title -> /community/news.php?title=post-title
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^community/news/(.*)$ example.com/community/news.php?title=$1 [L,QSA]
```